# Android's Gmail email sent event

Tags: android, contentobserver

Is there a way to capture a new email sent event ? I tried using  a ContentObserver on "content://gmail-ls/conversations" but still no luck.

any ideas highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I want to know this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today 2015-05-20, Google Gmail email cannot be accessed via

```
content://gmail-ls/
```

anymore